# Efficient way to build a navigation array out of a given database table, query advice

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, performance, navigation

I have following table "ProductCatalogCategories"

```
╔═══════════════════╤═════════════╤══════════════════╤══════════════════════╤═════════════╤══════╗
║ ProductCategoryID │ DisplayName │ ParentCategoryID │ PresentationSequence │ b_IsDeleted │ Code ║
╠═══════════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════════╪═════════════╪══════╣
║ 2                 │ Fruits      │                  │ 1                    │ 0           │      ║
╟───────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────╢
║ 4                 │ Banana      │ 2                │ 2                    │ 0           │      ║
╟───────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────╢
║ 6                 │ Apple       │ 2                │ 3                    │ 0           │      ║
╟───────────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼──────╢
║ 8                 │ Cars        │                  │ 2                    │ 0           │      ║
╚═══════════════════╧═════════════╧══════════════════╧══════════════════════╧═════════════╧══════╝
```

The table consists of following main columns:
The ProductCategoryID to identify the category,
the DisplayName,
and the ParentCategoryID to build the parent => child construct

my aim is to build an array looking something like this:

```
$aim = [
    "c_2"=>[
        "Name"=>"Fruits",
        "Children"=>[
             "c_4"=>[
                 "Name"=>"Banana",
                 "Children"=>[]
             ],
             "c_6"=>[
                 "Name"=>"Apple",
                 "Children"=>[]
             ]
        ]
    ],
    "c_8"=>[
        "Name"=>"Cars",
        "Children"=>[]
    ]
]
```

This construct is endlessly expandable, so i wanted to write a recursive function to get this construct and it works fine but not really great in performance:

```
$topLevel_q = sqlsrv_query($MSSQL, "SELECT ProductCategoryID,DisplayName,AccessGroupID FROM ProductCatalogCategories WHERE b_isDeleted = '0'  AND ParentCategoryID IS NULL AND NOT Code = 'CONTENT'  ORDER BY PresentationSequence ASC");
$topLevel = [];

$result = [];

while ($cat = sqlsrv_fetch_array($topLevel_q, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result["c_" . $cat["ProductCategoryID"]] = [
        "Name" => $cat["DisplayName"],
        "Children" => walkCats($cat["ProductCategoryID"], $MSSQL)
    ];
}

function walkCats($cat, $MSSQL) {
    $deeper = sqlsrv_query($MSSQL, "SELECT ProductCategoryID,DisplayName,AccessGroupID FROM ProductCatalogCategories WHERE b_isDeleted = '0'  AND ParentCategoryID='{$cat}' AND NOT Code = 'CONTENT'  ORDER BY PresentationSequence ASC");

    $next = [];

    while ($cat = sqlsrv_fetch_array($deeper, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $next["c_" . $cat["ProductCategoryID"]] = [
            "Name" => $cat["DisplayName"],
            "Children" => walkCats($cat["ProductCategoryID"], $MSSQL)
        ];
    }

    return $next;
}
```

Now to my question, is there a better way to get the construct?
I played around with some joins but i can't find to get my result with other queries.

The way it is now there will be easily 50 query calls with just 3-4 categories and all have 2-3 levels, there should be a better query for this problem, but im still unexperienced with advanced queries.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Google `Recursive CTE`, there are tons of examples.

Comment: Or prior to Recursive CTE you could use [ForXML Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This should work! You may also try to play around with your SQL query.

```
$topLevel_q = sqlsrv_query($MSSQL, "SELECT * FROM ProductCatalogCategories WHERE b_isDeleted = '0' AND NOT Code = 'CONTENT' ORDER BY ParentCategoryID DESC, PresentationSequence ASC");

$result = [];

while ($cat = sqlsrv_fetch_array($topLevel_q, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result["c_" . $cat["ProductCategoryID"]] = $cat;
}

foreach ($result as $key => &$categoryRow) {
    $parentId = ($categoryRow['ParentCategoryID'] > 0) ? $categoryRow['ParentCategoryID'] : 'root';
    if($parentId !== 'root')
        $result["c_" . $parentId]['Children'][$key] = $categoryRow;
    else
        $result[$parentId]['Children'][$key] = $categoryRow;

    if ($parentId !== 'root')
        unset($result[$key]);
}

if (!empty($result['root']['Children']) && $result['root']['Children'] && count($result['root']['Children']) > 1) {
    array_pop($result['root']['Children']);
}

$result = $result['root']['Children'];
```